# What's the difference between %s and %d in string formatting?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I don't understand what `%s` and `%d` do and how they work.

Answer (score 238):

They are used for formatting strings. `%s` acts a placeholder for a string while `%d` acts as a placeholder for a number. Their associated values are passed in via a tuple using the `%` operator.

```
name = 'marcog'
number = 42
print '%s %d' % (name, number)
```

will print `marcog 42`. Note that name is a string (%s) and number is an integer (%d for decimal).

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting for details.

In Python 3 the example would be:

```
print('%s %d' % (name, number))
```

Comment: In Google Chrome: Settings >> Search >> Manage search engines... notice how `%s` is used with search engine configurations. Chrome uses `%s` to replace keywords entered in the address bar. Python uses `%s` in a similar way. In `print('description: %s' % descrip)` the `%s` operator will be replaced by the text string stored in the `descrip` variable. The round braces prevent an error message in Python 3.

Comment: what do you call these %s, %d, etc?

Comment: @Chaine they are called Placeholders, they are replaceable variables

Answer (score 76):

from [python 3 doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html)

`%d` is for decimal integer

`%s` is for generic string or object and in case of object, it will be converted to string

Consider the following code

```
name ='giacomo'
number = 4.3
print('%s %s %d %f %g' % (name, number, number, number, number))
```

the out put will be

> giacomo 4.3 4 4.300000 4.3

as you can see `%d` will truncate to integer, `%s` will maintain formatting, `%f` will print as float and `%g` is used for generic number

obviously

```
print('%d' % (name))
```

will generate an exception; you cannot convert string to number

Comment: This deseeves more upvote. It explains what would happen if `%s` is used for a number instead.

Comment: What is the difference between %d and %i, if both will convert to integer? How does %d compare to %i and %f ?

Answer (score 40):

`%s` is used as a placeholder for string values you want to inject into a formatted string.

`%d` is used as a placeholder for numeric or decimal values.

For example (for python 3)

```
print ('%s is %d years old' % ('Joe', 42))
```

Would output

```
Joe is 42 years old
```

Comment: Doesn't really explain the problem?  I'm not explaining the problem, I'm providing a concise answer _to_ the question.  The question specifically asked what %s and %d were for.

Comment: do you know the difference between %i and %d? does python support %i?

Answer (score 39):

These are all informative answers, but none are quite getting at the core of what the difference is between `%s` and `%d`.

`%s` tells the formatter to call the `str()` function on the argument and since we are coercing to a string by definition, `%s` is essentially just performing `str(arg)`.

`%d` on the other hand, is calling `int()` on the argument before calling `str()`, like `str(int(arg))`, This will cause `int` coercion as well as `str` coercion.

For example, I can convert a hex value to decimal,

```
>>> '%d' % 0x15
'21'
```

or truncate a float.

```
>>> '%d' % 34.5
'34'
```

But the operation will raise an exception if the argument isn't a number.

```
>>> '%d' % 'thirteen'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

So if the intent is just to call `str(arg)`, then `%s` is sufficient, but if you need extra formatting (like formatting float decimal places) or other coercion, then the other format symbols are needed.

With the `f-string` notation, when you leave the formatter out, the default is `str`.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> f'{a}'
'1'
>>> f'{a:d}'
'1'
>>> a = '1'
>>> f'{a:d}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'
```

The same is true with `string.format`; the default is `str`.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> '{}'.format(a)
'1'
>>> '{!s}'.format(a)
'1'
>>> '{:d}'.format(a)
'1'
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the only one that actually explains the difference.

Comment: Given that I answered 9 years late, it's understandable. But, I was not satisfied with the answers so I added one.

Answer (score 11):

These are placeholders:

For example: `'Hi %s I have %d donuts' %('Alice', 42)`

This line of code will substitute %s with Alice (str) and %d with 42.

Output: `'Hi Alice I have 42 donuts'`

This could be achieved with a "+" most of the time. To gain a deeper understanding to your question, you may want to check {} / .format() as well. Here is one example: [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

also see here a google python tutorial video @ 40', it has some explanations
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk

Answer (score 10):

The `%d` and `%s` string formatting "commands" are used to format strings. The `%d` is for numbers, and `%s` is for strings.

For an example:

```
print("%s" % "hi")
```

and

```
print("%d" % 34.6)
```

To pass multiple arguments:

`print("%s %s %s%d" % ("hi", "there", "user", 123456))` will return `hi there user123456`

Comment: Note that `%d` is not any number. it's a decimal number (aka, integers). In the example above, `%d' %34.6` will output simply `34`. Same applies to `logger.info("value %d", 34.6)`

Answer (score 9):

`%d` and `%s` are placeholders, they work as a replaceable variable. For example, if you create 2 variables

```
variable_one = "Stackoverflow"
variable_two = 45
```

you can assign those variables to a sentence in a string using a tuple of the variables.

```
variable_3 = "I was searching for an answer in %s and found more than %d answers to my question"
```

Note that `%s` works for String and `%d` work for numerical or decimal variables.

if you print `variable_3` it would look like this

```
print(variable_3 % (variable_one, variable_two))
```

I was searching for an answer in StackOverflow and found more than 45 answers to my question.

Answer (score 4):

As per latest standards, this is how it should be done.

```
print("My name is {!s} and my number is{:d}".format("Agnel Vishal",100))
```

Do check [python3.6 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) and [sample program](https://github.com/agnelvishal/Condense.press/blob/master/backend/avarticle.py)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the basic example to demonstrate the Python string formatting and a new way to do it.

```
my_word = 'epic'
my_number = 1

print('The %s number is %d.' % (my_word, my_number))  # traditional substitution with % operator
```

//The epic number is 1.

```
print(f'The {my_word} number is {my_number}.')  # newer format string style
```

//The epic number is 1.

Both prints the same.

Answer (score 3):

speaking of which ... 
python3.6 comes with `f-strings` which  makes things much easier in formatting!

now if your python version is greater than 3.6 you can format your strings with these available methods:

```
name = "python"

print ("i code with %s" %name)          # with help of older method
print ("i code with {0}".format(name))  # with help of format
print (f"i code with {name}")           # with help of f-strings
```

Answer (score 3):

%s is used to hold space for string
%d is used to hold space for number

```
name = "Moses";
age = 23
print("My name is %s am CEO at MoTech Computers " %name)
print("Current am %d years old" %age)
print("So Am %s and am %d years old" %(name,age))
```

[Program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qmGS.png)

this video goes deep about that tip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zN5YsuiqMA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How is your answer different the other 12?

Comment: almost those format works the same but all i wanted is to give more examples so as to increase an understanding

Comment: That's great! You can improve your answer by adding the program output as a text and not as an image.

Comment: thanks for your concern, i'll make some changes, you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

In case you would like to avoid %s or %d then..

```
name = 'marcog'
number = 42
print ('my name is',name,'and my age is:', number)
```

Output:

```
my name is marcog and my name is 42
```

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question? The questioner was asking about use of `%s` and `%d`.

Comment: BTW, the code you show is invalid in Python 3.5.1: `print` is a function in Python 3, not a statement.

Comment: I have edited the post ...please see it. Actually, I posted it as an alternative..if some one might avoid using %d or %s. And thanks for the error detection, ..I have edited the code.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Unfortunately, this still isn't an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

for example you can use %s and %d and %f like as below:

```
name = 'Ali' ;age = 25  ; live = 'Tehran' ; salary = 1526.73

print('%s is %d years old. he is living in %s and earn %f per month.' % (name, age, live, salary))
```

Comment: How is this answer different than the ones posted before? For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31279690/15032126), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64240982/15032126), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60271212/15032126)?

Comment: It is especially important to check existing answers on old questions like this one (it was asked 13 years ago).