# python what does "%ds" mean in format?

Tags: python-2.7

What does "%ds" in following codes mean?

```
theline = 'aaaaaeeebbbbbbbbccccccccddd'
baseformat = "5s 3x 8s 8s"
numremain = len(theline) - struct.calcsize(baseformat)
format = "%s %ds" % (baseformat, numremain)
s1, s2, s3, s4= struct.unpack(format, theline)
```

Comment: This might help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/s-and-d-python

Comment: I know the meaning of "%s" or "%d", but I can not understand the usage of "%ds"

Comment: Its a String starting with a digit. ex:2a,3b

Answer (score 7):

The `'%ds'` is not a format specifier. It's `'%d'` followed by `'s'`:

```
>>> "%ds" % 6
6s
```

Answer (score 1):

"%ds" here is a format specifier plus a single string "s". For the codes above, it specifies the length of "remain string".