# How can I get my program to print floats?

Tags: python, string, math, floating-point, geometry

I've written a small program to help me with my math homework:

```
import math
def saCircle():
    while True: 
        radius = float(raw_input("Enter the radius: "))
        print "\nFinding area with %d as the radius" % radius  
        x = math.pi * radius**2
        print "\nThe area of your circle is %d\n" % x 
saCircle()
```

The problem is that it will accept a decimal number but it will not print out the value of the decimal number.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%f` instead of `%d` (rounds your number to an integer) to print a float:

```
>>> radius = 4.4
>>> x = math.pi * radius**2
>>> print "\nThe area of your circle is %f\n" % x

The area of your circle is 60.821234
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/s-and-d-python) question explains the difference very well.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier for floats is `%f`, not `%d` (`%d` is for integers).

```
print "\nFinding area with %f as the radius" % radius
                           ^
```

See the Wikipedia article on [`printf` format strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) for more details.

Comment: Thank you... I will be taking a look.