# Tuple and placeholder interaction with python print()?

Tags: python, tuples

I have run below 4 sets of statements, and they give different result. I am unsure about the cause of the difference. Please see notes below -

#### Case1

'usercount' coerced to tuple, why does formatting work when it becomes a tuple? Is coerced the right term here?

```
usercount=(6)  #integer value
print ("Users connected: %d"%(usercount,))  
Users connected: 6
```

#### Case2

%s or %d makes no difference, if its a tuple, print function works the same way.

```
usercount=(6)
print ("Users connected: %s"%(usercount,))
Users connected: 6
```

#### Case3

'usercount' declared as tuple, print fxn works fine with %s placeholder.

```
usercount=(6,) # now tuple
print ("Users connected: %s"%(usercount,))
Users connected: (6,)
```

#### Case4

Same case %d placeholder throws an error, number required, not tuple.

```
usercount=(6,)
print ("Users connected: %d"%(usercount,))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-02d2ce66d935> in <module>()
      1 usercount=(6,)
----> 2 print ("Users connected: %d"%(usercount,))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not tuple
```

Also, both placeholders work, when tuple declared the other way.

```
usercount=(6,)
print ("Users connected: %s"%(usercount))
Users connected: 6

usercount=(6,)
print ("Users connected: %d"%(usercount))
Users connected: 6
```

Comment: `(usercount)` does not declare a tuple. It is just `usercount` with parentheses around it.

Comment: @KlausD. (usercount,) and usercount=(6,) are the tuples

Comment: I am unclear what  the question here is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its good to know that you should use %s for strings %d(decimal) for numbers, you can read this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d-in-python-string-formatting?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for getting better information about these two. 
but in your cases:

### Case1:

the `usercount=(6)` lines just returns an Integer value and its true way to use `%d`.

### Case2:

the `usercount=(6)` lines just returns an Integer value and its can be casted to string and printed so you can use`%s` for that too.

### Case3:

the `usercount=(6,)` lines just returns a Tuple value and its can be casted to string and printed so you can use`%s` for that too.

### Case4:

the `usercount=(6,)` lines just returns a Tuple value and in this case you can not cast a tuple to an Integer so you cant use `%d` for that.

Comment: Thanks, this is succinct.