# Inserting variables into a SQL Query in Python using requests

Tags: python, sql, python-requests

I have the following:

```
for name in set(short_names):
    n = name.title()

    url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
    query = """
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      ?item rdfs:label "____________"@en

    }
    """
    r = requests.get(url, params = {'format': 'json', 'query': query})
    data = r.json()
    url = data.get('results').get('bindings')[0].get('item').get('value')
    q_id = re.search('Q.*', url).group()

    client = Client()  
    entity = client.get(q_id, load=True)
    d = entity.description
    desc.append(d)
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is insert the 'n' variable into _______ on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your indentation may be off if you want your `query` variable to change on each iteration of the loop but you can do something like this:

```
for name in set(short_names):
    n = name.title()

    url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
    query = """
    SELECT ?item WHERE {
      ?item rdfs:label "%s"@en

    }
    """ % (n)
    r = requests.get(url, params = {'format': 'json', 'query': query})
    data = r.json()
    url = data.get('results').get('bindings')[0].get('item').get('value')
    q_id = re.search('Q.*', url).group()

    client = Client()  
    entity = client.get(q_id, load=True)
    d = entity.description
    desc.append(d)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

%s formatting: [What's the difference between %s and %d in Python string formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d-in-python-string-formatting)

Edited: realized that the other {} after the WHERE brake the format and f-string functions. Using the %s string formatting to avoid that potential issue.

Comment: I get a "KeyError: '\n      ?item rdfs'" error. Also: "
ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 4))"

Comment: you're right, those curly braces do break it. I'll update it again to use the %s string formatting