# Why should I use %d for integer in python3?

Tags: python, formatting

From experience using `%d` or `%s` when formatting an integer in python 2 and 3 gives the same result. On top of that, it seems that using `%s` instead of `%d` when formatting an integer is a few nanoseconds faster.

Why should I ever use `%d` when formatting an integer since it seems to have absolutely no effect on the final result?

```
In [8]: "foo %s bar" % 1000
Out[8]: 'foo 1000 bar'

In [9]: "foo %d bar" % 1000
Out[9]: 'foo 1000 bar'
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d-in-python-string-formatting/48660475

Comment: You might use `%d` to indicate that the parameter is an integer, and cause an error if it is not one.

Comment: you can get the same result using print(f"foo {1000} bar")

Comment: Also, see what `"%d"%1.5` does in comparison to `"%s"%1.5`

Comment: Or you can use format