# What does the %s placeholder stand for?

Tags: python, string-formatting, mysql-connector-python

I am learning to use MySQL Connector/Python. In most of the tutorials, I see they use the `%s` placeholder inside `VALUES` clause for inserting data in a table. Then, on the next line, the values are stored in a tuple. And then, they `execute` the command.

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("Foo", "Bar")
cursor.execute(sql, val)
```

So what does this `%s` mean? Is it the same as the one used in **C**? I saw people using this in **C**. I am just curious. Please do give any reference link, if any. Thanks.

Comment: %s ia a placeholder for a string, I suggest this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d-in-python-string-formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells the string that the value will be converted to a string and replace the placeholder at that position.

But the connector also supports prepared statements.

```
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"""

insert_tuple_1 = ("Json", "BAker street")
insert_tuple_2 = ("Emma", "Avenue des Champs-Élysées")

cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, insert_tuple_1)
cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, insert_tuple_2)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks! And does the 's' stand for 'string'?

Comment: yes, as stated in the answer `converted to a string`