# How to fetch integer values using parameters into a MySQL database with Python connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to fetch data from a MySQL database using python connector. I want to fetch records matching the `ID`. The ID has an integer data type. This is the code:

```py
custID = int(input("Customer ID: "))
executeStr = "SELECT * FROM testrec WHERE ID=%d"

cursor.execute(executeStr, custID)
custData = cursor.fetchall()

if bool(custData):
    pass
else:
    print("Wrong Id")
```

But the code is raising an error which says:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '%d' at line 1
```

Any ideas why the integer placeholder `%d`  is producing this?

Comment: Libraries use different paramstyle. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string only accepts %s or %(name)s , not %d.

```
executeStr = "SELECT * FROM testrec WHERE ID=%s"
```

and the variables are supposed to be in a tuple, although that varies by implementation depending on what version you are using, you might need to use:

```
cursor.execute(executeStr, (custID,))
```

More information here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

The [current version](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/tree/403535dbdd45d894c780da23ba96b1a6c81e3866) supports variables of types: `int`,`long`,`float`,`string`,`unicode`,`bytes`,`bytearray`,`bool`,`none`,`datetime.datetime`,`datetime.date`,`datetime.time`,`time.struct_time`,`datetime.timedelta`, and `decimal.Decimal`

Comment: But what if I want to insert an integer value. If the the SQL table column has datatype of `INT`, then inserting string will fail.

Comment: %s != string, this isn't a C/C++ formatted string.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Now I get it. I had asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64953563/what-does-the-s-placeholder-stand-for about `%s` few days ago, but no one mentioned me that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The article I link puts it well: "The data values are converted as necessary from Python objects to something MySQL understands."  i.e. it checks the type of each variable before passing it over so it knows to use quotes or not etc.

Answer (score -2):

Your should try %s not %d. This is because your data type of MYSQL may be int but the parameter you should pass to cursor must be string.

Try this:

```
custID = int(input("Customer ID: "))
executeStr  = 'SELECT * FROM testrec WHERE ID=%s'%(custID,)

cursor.execute(executeStr, custID)
custData = cursor.fetchall()

if bool(custData):
    pass
else:
    print("Wrong Id")
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But, can you please explain the `%(custID,)`. What does that do?

Comment: That's not true at all, the parameter can be in lots of different types, it doesn't have to be a string. https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/403535dbdd45d894c780da23ba96b1a6c81e3866/lib/mysql/connector/conversion.py#L179 search for `to_mysql` in this file and you'll see all of the type conversions it supports

Comment: @ShounakDas ```%(custID,)``` is a tuple that passes the argument, where ever you pass ```%s``` , you can also use ```%s``` two times and pass ```%(val1,val2)```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of this:

```sql
custID = int(input("Customer ID: "))
executeStr = "SELECT * FROM testrec WHERE ID=%d"
```

You should write:

```sql
custID = int(input("Customer ID: "))
executeStr = "SELECT * FROM testrec WHERE ID='"+custID+"';"
```