# What does % means in python aside from modulus?

Tags: python

I've been seeing the % sign in python tutorials but they're not using it like modulo.

This is the code from Python app tutorial:

```
message = 'GIEWIVrGMTLIVrHIQS' #encrypted message
LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

for key in range(len(LETTERS)):
   translated = ''
   for symbol in message:
      if symbol in LETTERS:
         num = LETTERS.find(symbol)
         num = num - key
         if num < 0:
            num = num + len(LETTERS)
         translated = translated + LETTERS[num]
      else:
         translated = translated + symbol
print('Hacking key #%s: %s' % (key, translated))
```

This line:

```
    print('Hacking key #%s: %s' % (key, translated))
```

I don't also know the # sign and the s, I am thinking they're regular expression but they didn't import regular expression

Comment: These are comprehensively answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d-in-python-string-formatting

Comment: Whatever tutorial you found this on is really old. If you're using Python 3 you should use the more modern string formatting options which are the `str.format()` method and `f-strings`

Answer (score 1):

`#` is an normal text. and `%s` means string format.
`%s` acts a placeholder for a string while `%d` acts as a placeholder for a number
You can use `%s` as putting str into str, and `%d` is int. you can contain int into str using this.

and if you do `% (key, translated)`
then that means putting multiple arguments for string format.

And now, use `str.format()` and for python ver 3.6↑ use `f` string format.