# What does %s" % stand for in a Python print statement

Tags: python, file

I have been studying pickling and unpickling and a came across this - can someone please explain what it stands for?

[This is the code that led to the confusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH6FU.jpg)

Comment: This should answer your question: [What's the difference between %s and %d in Python string formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288973/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d-in-python-string-formatting)

Comment: Curious that you learnt about `pickle` before learning about string formating

Comment: `%s` is so python 2 . . . try `f-strings`

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` is a placeholder for strings using the old formatting methods in python. Essentially `%s` gets replaced by the string value of `my_int` in your example. Here is some documentation provided by @Paul Cornelius: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting.

There are a few newer ways to do this if you want to in your own code that work a bit better, pickle likely uses the old style because they have no real reason to upgrade.

### F-strings

in python 3.6+ you can use fstrings by putting an f in front of a string declaration and using `{variable_name}` to access a value. like in this example:

```py
name = "John Smith" # A dummy name

email_count = 3 # A representation of users # of new emails

current_temperature = 20.3567 # A representation of the current temperature in celsius 

greeting = f"Hello, {name} The weather today is {current_temperature} degrees. You have {email_count} new emails."

print(greeting)
```

Which would result in printing

`Hello John Smith The weather today is 20.3567 degrees. You have 3 new emails.`

This is equivalent using the % method to doing:

```py
name = "John Smith" # A dummy name

email_count = 3 # A representation of users # of new emails

current_temperature = 20.3567 # A representation of the current temperature in celsius 

greeting = "Hello, %s The weather today is %03.2f degrees. You have %d new emails." % (name, current_temperature, email_count)

print(greeting)
```

Where `%s` is replaced by a string, `%03.2f` is replaced by a float rounded to the nearest 2 decimal places, and `%d` is replaced by an integer. One of the main reasons this method got replaced is because F-strings are easier to read, and don't require you to know the types of everything being put into them ahead of time (just uses the `__repr__()` of the object), whereas for example `%d` will only work with integers, or objects that can have `int(obj)` called on them.

Comment: FYI, what you say about % formatting is absolutely true, but it is still part of the language and is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: @PaulCornelius Perfect, I knew it was still part of it, just couldn't find the docs because they moved them from 2-3. I will update the answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`%` means parameter passed into the string.
`%s` is parameter that should be treated as string
There are some other kinds of parameters types used there like `%d` for decimal integers, `%f` for floating point numbers etc.